# Ajax load image an ddisplay it with dataURI

Tags: jquery, cordova, data-uri

I am trying with phonegap and jquery to do the following.
Load an image with $.ajax(), store it on localStorage, and show it in the html page.

```
$.ajax({
 type: 'GET',
 url: uri,
 success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  if (textStatus === "notmodified") {
    console.log("NOT modified.");
  } else {
    console.log("download complete. Total Bytes: " + data.length);
    window.localStorage.setItem(fileName,btoa(encodeURIComponent(data)));
  }
 }
})
```

then later on:

```
$('#info img').each( function() {
 var fileName = this.src;
 var pos = fileName.lastIndexOf('/');

 if(pos >= 0)
  fileName = fileName.substring(pos + 1);

 //Check for image
 var pos = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
 var ext;
 if(pos >= 0)
   ext = fileName.substring(pos + 1);

 if(fileName in filesSynchronized)
  this.src = 'data:image/' + ext +';base64,' + window.localStorage[fileName];
```

but image is corrupted. What am I doing wrong? Doesn't ajax return a byte array for the image? Doesn't btoa work correctly?

Comment: what is the `Content-Type` of the AJAX response?

Answer (score 0):

One way to answer your questions - take the `base64` encoded image from `localStorage`, decode it and compare it with the source file you send to the browser.

If they are not identical, then the answer to at least one of your questions is YES.